# How to set up Unity Console Server?

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, console

I am relatively new to the Unity server implementation, so, I don't have a lot of experience. Anyways, since Networking is so big of a topic, I think I can get some help from you guys. I am working on an Android Game and it is a 2D Game with NO movement or physics needs. I need a server just to handle some basic calculations and send the result in a form of a 2D Array to the Client and the server should also handle the accounts info in a MySQL Database( not a lot of experience here, but there is a little) and the "Monetization" system, like the gold coins and stuff like that. So, I don't need a very complicated server, just simple enough for the tasks I listed above.

Now, the things that I don't understand are these:

1)I would like to have my server as a .NET Socket API running as a Console, but, by the looks of things, there are not many great tutorials and a lot to cover...Do I have any other options?

2)I can't predict the future, but let's suppose that my game is going pretty well with a lot of players playing at the same time....maybe in the thousands. If I rent a VPS from Google, would it be able to run the Console Server for all those players? The thing I don't understand is how Supercell or Rockstars(some basic example) manage their servers with so many people playing?

Anyways, obviously you can't give me the source code for a "complete" server but the purpose of this post is to get a correct starting point for the right path. What should I learn specifically in order to build a dedicated server with MySQL support in Unity? What tutorials should I follow? What should I expect along the way? I would like to get in contact with someone that has experience in this field and help me as little as possible, but people are minding their own business so I guess no luck with that... Would a VPS rented by google be able to handle some hundreds or thousands of people?

I know I didn't use some professional language and some laughable phrases but I can't do anything about it until I learn more and more along the way. Thank you!